# CIs for proportions in Stata: ci vs. proportion command

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, proportion

I'm performing some basic analysis on a large data set (n-size after restrictions about 4,000) to supplement some qualitative historical research. The goal is to produce a variety of confidence intervals for proportions, and I've run the analysis in Stata using both the `ci` command (with `aweights`) and the `proportion` command (with `pweights`). The means generated by `ci` are more or less identical to the proportions generated by `proportion`, but there is more noticeable (though not very substantial) variation in the confidence intervals.

I'm wondering if there is a strong theoretical reason to opt for either the `ci` or the `proportion` command here? I'm guessing the latter given the sample size.

Answer (score 2):

The essence of this question is statistical, although as phrased it is not likely to mean much to non-Stata users.

Yes, there is a reason, and it doesn't have to be called "theoretical" as it is practical too.

The reasons for using `pweights` with `proportion` would be, and could only be, that you

1. Have survey data so declared, which is why you are using `pweights` at all.
2. Cannot do that calculation in `ci`.

`proportion` has other uses too.

To spell out a little what is meant by "survey data": Survey design characteristics often 
include sampling weights, one or more stages of clustered sampling, and stratification.

If that's so, there is not really any question of choice or shopping around: `ci` is not the command to use for survey data.

Comment: Thanks again, just to follow up so I'm clear about what the software is doing. With the "ci" command it's automatically assuming a simple random sample?

Comment: The command is written on that assumption. The code isn't sentient, although no doubt that is a pedantic distinction.